# NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, variables, compiler-errors, iboutlet

When I run my application I get this error:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
     [UIRoundedRectButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
     0xcc86970'
```

Why I get an error like this? I was careful to check all connection of IBOutlets e all IBAction. This is my code:

MenuViewController.h

```
     @interface MenuViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

}


@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView;
@property (nonatomic,copy) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonHome;
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonMap;
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonFavorites;

 -(IBAction) pressedHome:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) pressedMap: (id)sender;
-(IBAction) pressedFavorites: (id)sender;

 @end
```

In MenuViewController.m

```
 -(IBAction) pressedHome:(id)sender{

     MenuViewController * menu =[[MenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];


    }

  -(IBAction) pressedMap: (id)sender{

       MapViewController * map =[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:map animated:YES];
   }


  -(IBAction) pressedFavorites: (id)sender{

        FavoritesViewController * favorites =[[FavoritesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FavoritesViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:favorites animated:YES];
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the `copy`. This is happening because UIButton (and other UIControls) don't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, so the call to copy them fails.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `copy` for the following properties

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonHome;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonMap;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonFavorites;
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this? Can you add some comment?

Comment: that's enough to fix the crash

Comment: Ok, but [check how to write a good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [here too](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx)